# Route redirection is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

After successfully login in my Laravel application, it takes me to dashbaord. After logout from the application it takes me to the login page again. But if I click back icon from the browser It will take me to dashboard again though I have `log out`.

**routes**

```
Route::get('/admin-login', 'userController@index');
Route::post('/admin-login', 'userController@admin_login');
Route::get('/admin-logout', 'userController@admin_logout');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboardController@index');
```

**dashboardController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class dashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/admin-login'); //This Redirection Doesn't Work
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Where is the problem I can't find out. Please Anybody help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**Redirecting to named routes**

`return redirect()->route('admin-login');`

**OR**

**Redirecting to controller actions**

`return redirect()->action('yourController@yourMethod');`

And make sure you have prevent back history in your middleware.

**Create New Middleware**
php artisan make:middleware PreventBackHistory

once you create PreventBackHistory middleware it will be in app/Http/Middleware/PreventBackHistory.php and add following code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
```

**Register Middleware**

open Kernel.php(app/Http/Kernel.php) and add our new middleware in $routeMiddleware variable array.

`'prevent-back-history' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,`

**Use Middleware In Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'prevent-back-history'],function(){
        Route::get('/admin-login', 'userController@index');
        Route::post('/admin-login', 'userController@admin_login');
        Route::get('/admin-logout', 'userController@admin_logout');
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboardController@index');
});
```

Comment: @NaramukAbus.......No change of result. Still go to the dashboard though logout

Comment: Did you create 'Prevent Back History' middleware ?